# Xamarin iOS Error on try debug application on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

When we try to debug application on device (iPhone 5) get error

> MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Linq.Expressions.BlockExpression System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Block(System.Type,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)"

This bug marked as solved don't help us.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=14765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your Linq statement that is causing this. I faced this problem once (I was using a third party DB), Unfortunately the actual devices don't support JIT but the simulator does. Do your Linq statement differently.

Comment: Did you change all linq statments like this ```return persistFacilities.Select(f => f.ToCore(facility));``` ? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Normal select statements will work. I think what's throwing it off is the call to `ToCore`. I would use a normal for loop instead of the select for it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to consider if you use, even indirectly, `System.Linq.Expressions` (SLE).

1. This requires code generation and that's not something possible under iOS. This feature is [not supported](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/) on Xamarin.iOS. SLE is part of the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR);
2. There is *partial* support for SLE using an interpreter. That has been shipped with Xamarin.iOS for long time - but it only provide a subset of the features. Sadly the existing API is not 100% identical to the one used by MS and it can
   [cause issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22066893/220643) when building (e.g. using PCL assemblies). This is why you're getting those `MT2002` errors (your assembly tries to override an non-existing member).
3. A maintenance release of Xamarin.iOS (7.2.1+) includes a better (more features) and API-compatible SLE interpreter.